# Emulate clean checkout

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am using Jenkins for my build machine. First I did checkout via plugin and used "Emulate clean checkout by first deleting unversioned/ignored files then update SVN. Like so: 
[image]
For some reasons I neded it to be sone via script. So I changet to:
[image]
But the "Emulate clean checkout...." (marked with red arrow) is not working and not deleting unversioned/ignored files. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your script works..

Perhaps you need to cd into each directory first and then execute the corresponding actions?

```
cd AC-AndroiStable
svn status --no-ignore | grep '^[I?]' | cut -c 9- | while IFS= read -r f; do rm -rf "$f"; done
cd ../VersionControl
svn status --no-ignore | grep '^[I?]' | cut -c 9- | while IFS= read -r f; do rm -rf "$f"; done
...
```

Answer (score -1):

For `svn status` to return the information that you want, you must either run it within the existing working copies, or you must **add a path argument**:

```
svn status --no-ignore VersionControl
```

As the `svn status` output parsing is ugly, and checking for actual presence of working copies is cumbersome, **it will be easier (and safer)** to just use this single line command:

```
rm -rf VersionControl AndroidStable
```